# Select object by name with index

Tags: jquery, indexing

HTML:

```
<tr class="items">
    <td>
        <select name="type[0]">
            <option value="1">Goods</option><option value="2">Work</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pn[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="qty[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price[0]"></td>
</tr>
<tr class="items">
    <td>
        <select name="type[1]">
            <option value="1">Goods</option><option value="2">Work</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pn[1]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="qty[1]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price[1]"></td>
</tr>
```

Problem: A need empty and disable pn[1] when type[1] changed to value 2. What is the jQuery selector for indexed fields?

I want to use something like this:

```
$('select[name="type[*index*]"]').change(function(){
    if($(this).value == 2){
        $('input[name="pn[*index*]"]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('input[name="pn[*index*]"]').prop('disabled', false);
    }
})
```

but I don't know how to read index in name attribute of $(this) and how to select object by name with index.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("select[name^='type']").change(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $("input[name^='pn']", row).prop("disabled", $(this).val() === "2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="items">
    <td>
      <select name="type[0]">
        <option value="1">Goods</option>
        <option value="2">Work</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pn[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="qty[0]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price[0]"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="items">
    <td>
      <select name="type[1]">
        <option value="1">Goods</option>
        <option value="2">Work</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="pn[1]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="qty[1]"></td>
    <td><input type="number" name="price[1]"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

When `select` is changed, it disabled the `pn[]` element and disabled it as needed.

This is making use of the Starts With attribute selector `^=`, see more: https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: It's working only for the first line in my code. Other lines are dynamically added after page loaded by link with onclick function $('.items:last').after('<tr> ... </tr>');

Comment: @Kenapuc you did not specify that in your post. You would want to change it to use delete event, with `$("table").on("change", "select[name^='type']", function(){ })`